# How to exclude directory from find results if any of its parent directories contain a specific file

Tags: linux, command-line, find, search, suse

Im trying to use the find command to recursively search a directory tree and return all results with a directory matching a given name.

```
find . -type d -name '<NAME>'
```

I get a list of paths returned which are printed into a log file. I want to be able to omit any results which contain a file called omit.txt within a parent directory.

./parent_directory/
NAME>

I have been trying to do it with the following

```
find . -type d -name '<NAME>' \( ! -wholename "*omit.txt*" -prune \)
```

I am trying to use the prune command to omit results containing the file, but I think this may only work with directories. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am trying to do this in just one command and maintain the output file as much as possible -

Comment: So, if we have `./a/x/omit.txt` and `./b/x/foo.txt`, you'd want a listing that only contains `./b/x/`? Can you add a mock-up sample directory tree and the expected output on the question?

Comment: So in a directory tree where the is ./a ./b ./c and each of those directories contains a directory called d, giving ./a/d  ./b/d ./c/d. if i was to place a file called omit.txt into directory c, /i want to try and use the find unix command to return any case where there is directory called 'd' in the directory tree AND the file 'omit.txt' is not present within the parent directory. So you would expect it to return './a/d ./b/d' .  , with my attempt above it returns './a/d ./b/d ./c/d'

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do this completely within `find`, since you need to be able to see the file inside the directory when processing the directory. `-prune` has to operate on the directory itself, but `-path` and other conditions only see the file name after `find` has already descended to the directory.

All I can come up with is to fork off a shell to peek inside the directory. Something like this:

```
$ mkdir -p x y/z ; touch x/foo y/omit.txt
$ find -type d \( -exec sh -c '[ -e "$1/omit.txt" ]' sh {} \; -prune -o -print \)
.
./x
```

`foo -o bar` does not evaluate `bar` if `foo` succeeds, so if the directory is pruned, the print doesn't run. Add `-o -print` to the end to print the directory contents too. We can't use `exec ... {} +` here, since we need this to act as a condition for each directory separately.

Comment: Now that I see this I remember seeing a similar answer/question here some months back that took the same approach. Don't have time to `find` it now, though. ;)

Comment: Thanks, you gave me a lot to work with here, I think I will read up on some of the arguments you used here. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If busybox is available on your system, you can do:

```
busybox find . -type d '(' -exec [ -e '{}/omit.txt' ] ';' -prune \
  -o -name '<NAME>' -print ')'
```

The `find` of busybox, like that of GNU does expand `{}` to the path of the file even if it's only *part* of an argument avoiding having to resort to `sh`, but more importantly, in recent versions, it is able to run the `[` applet without a fork() nor execve() so it makes it several orders of magnitude more efficient than with most other `find` implementations.

If a directory called `<NAME>` may itself contain a `omit.txt` and you want to print it in that case even if still pruned, you can change it to:

```
busybox find . -type d '(' -exec [ ! -e '{}/omit.txt' ] ';' -o -prune ')' \
  -name '<NAME>'
```

In the bosh (not bash) shell, `find` (like `[`) is built-in and is able to run some shell code without forking with its `-call` predicate which would also save fork()s and execve()s:

```
find . -type d '(' -call '[ -e "$1/omit.txt" ]' {} ';' -prune \
  -o -name '<NAME>' -print ')'
```

A more portable alternative is to use `find`'s `File::Find` module.

```
perl -MFile::Find -le '
  find sub {
    if (-e "$_/omit.txt") {
      $File::Find::prune = 1;
    } else {
      print $File::Find::name if ($_ eq "<NAME>") && -d;
    }
  }, @ARGV' -- .
```

Answer (score 0):

@ilkkachu gave an awesome answer to a question I've had for a while! Definitely give them your upvotes. I just wanted to add a couple of variations I used that might benefit someone else :)

*sample outputs are based on the following structure*

```
./
├── a/
│   ├── b/
│   │   └── world.txt
│   └── hello.txt
├── foo.txt
└── some_git_repo/
    ├── .git/
    ├── README
    └── c/
        └── some_git_submodule/
            ├── .git/
            └── README
```

### Print all directories EXCEPT git repos

```bash
find . -type d \( -exec sh -c 'test -e "$1/.git"' sh {} \; -prune -o -print \)
```

```
.
./a
./a/b
```

### 1. Print all directories, INCLUDING git repos

### 2. DO NOT recurse into any git repos

```bash
find . -type d \( -exec sh -c 'test -e "$1/.git"' sh {} \; -print -prune -o -print \)
```

```
.
./a
./a/b
./some_git_repo
```

### Print all files, EXCEPT those in git repos

```bash
find . \( -exec sh -c 'test -e "$1/.git"' sh {} \; -prune -o -type f -print \)
```

```
./foo.txt
./a/b/world.txt
./a/hello.txt
```

### 1. Print all files, EXCEPT those in git repos

### 2. Print the excluded git dirs

```bash
find . \( -exec sh -c 'test -e "$1/.git"' sh {} \; -print -prune -o -type f -print \)
```

```
./foo.txt
./a/b/world.txt
./a/hello.txt
./some_git_repo
```

---

And then for the opposite...

### Print all git repos

```bash
find . -type d \( -exec sh -c 'test -e "$1/.git"' sh {} \; -print -prune \)
```

```
./some_git_repo
```

### Print all git repos including submodules

```bash
find . -type d \( -exec sh -c 'test -e "$1/.git"' sh {} \; -print \) -o \( -name '.git' -prune \)
```

```
./some_git_repo
./some_git_repo/c/some_git_submodule
```